# Insert Array in Phpmyadmin database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to insert a array in my database and I selected 3 values like broccoli,carrots,Cabbage but only broccoli is inserted ang those 2 values are not inserted can someone help me with this thank you.

**Servlet**

```
String[] vege = request.getParameterValues("vegetables-selected");

Model mod = new Model();

mod.setVegetables(vege);
```

**Model**

```
    private String[] Vegetables;

public String[] getVegetables() {
        return Vegetables;
    }

    public void setVegetables(String[] vegetables) {
        Vegetables = vegetables;
    }
```

**Operation**

```
[public static int AddRecipes(Model mod) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        Driver(dbloader);
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(Add_Recipe);
        pst.setInt(1, mod.getUsers_ID());
        pst.setString(2, mod.getTitle());
        pst.setString(3, mod.getVegetables());

        i = pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return i;

}
```

[Click this for photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boQn7.png)

Comment: I don't think your code compiles. What error do you get when you compile it?

Comment: I only get 1 value but I choose 3 vegetables like broccoli,carrots,cabbage only broccoli inserted in my database